# How to return a reference to a new object without memory leaks? c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, pass-by-reference

I'm writing macros for debugging system

I have an overloaded chained operator `<<(MessageAssembler& target,message_type msg)`
(`message_type`) is a template parameter for the operator

It adds `msg` to `target`'s inner variable of type `QTextStream`.

The operator `+=(MessageAssembler& result)` of `MessageAssembler` passes `result`'s stream to function which processes it based on parameters of `result`.

I want to do something like this:

```
#define FATAL(facility) NLog::assembler+=MessageAssembler(Log::fatal_sev,facility)<< __FILE__<<":"<<__LINE__
```

(`NLog::assembler` is a static variable of type `MessageAssembler`)

It should determine output's facility, allow a user to add its own message to output by using

```
FATAL(some_facility)<<"custom message"<<ObjectWhichCanBePassedToQTextStream()<<AnotherObject();
```

But `MessageAssembler(Log::fatal_sev,facility)` produces `a reference to temporary` error.

This

```
MessageAssembler& MessageAssembler::get_instance(Log::Severity _msg_sev,Log::Facility _msg_fac)
{
    MessageAssembler tmp(_msg_sev,_msg_fac);
    return tmp;
}
```

will return a reference to a non-existing object;

This

```
MessageAssembler& MessageAssembler::get_instance(Log::Severity _msg_sev,Log::Facility _msg_fac)
{
    return new MessageAssembler tmp(_msg_sev,_msg_fac);
}
```

will cause a memory leak

This

```
QScopedPointer<MessageAssembler> MessageAssembler::get_instance(Log::Severity _msg_sev,Log::Facility _msg_fac)
{
    return QScopedPointer<MessageAssembler>(new MessageAssembler tmp(_msg_sev,_msg_fac));
}
```

will not work because `QScopedPointer` can't be passed by value

I'm not sure if storing second static variable `MessageAssembler chain_starter;` is thread-safe.

I have not only `FATAL` macro, so the program won't be always terminated after the call.

How can i return a reference to a new `MessageAssembler`?

**EDIT:** My problem was solved by installing a third-party library for smart pointer, namely, yasper. The general solution is proposed by πάντα ῥεῖ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most concise answer is:

**Don't do it using raw pointers!** Use the c++ [smart pointer features](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead.

The most straightforward implementation seems to be, creating a `std::unique_ptr<MessageAssembler>` instance and return this one. The calling client will receive ownership of the created instance and it will be deleted automatically, as soon that reference goes out of scope.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without `unique_ptr`? Because QtCreator in Ubuntu produces `error: 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a type static std::unique_ptr<MessageAssembler>`. I'm not sure if I convince others to change compiler setting for this issue and that changing the settings is possible.

Comment: @user2136963 Qt usually goes well with specifying `-std=c++11`, though you didn't narrow your question being restricted by such considerations.